Moving Out Of Stock Products To The End Of Pages In The WP-E-Commerce Plugin (WPEC)
Currently when you browse through the products pages on our wp-e-commerce Wordpress site, all of the out of stock products show across all the pages.
What we would like to be able to to do, is to move all of the out of stock products to the end of the pages, so that in order to view the out of stock products, you would have to scroll through all the pages, which would be showing the products that are in stock, in order to improve the user experience.
We would like to be able to either come up with a filter to go in functions.php, or change the below code to achieve this:
function wpsc_product_sort_order_query_vars( $orderby = null ) {
if ( is_null( $orderby ) ) {
    $orderby = get_option( 'wpsc_sort_by' );
}

$query_vars = array();

switch ( $orderby ) {

    case "dragndrop":
        $query_vars["orderby"] = 'menu_order';
        break;

    case "name":
        $query_vars["orderby"] = 'title';
        break;

    //This only works in WP 3.0.
    case "price":
        add_filter( 'posts_join', 'wpsc_add_meta_table' );
        add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpsc_add_meta_table_where' );
        $query_vars["meta_key"] = '_wpsc_price';
        $query_vars["orderby"] = 'meta_value_num';
        break;

    case "id":
        $query_vars["orderby"] = 'ID';
        break;
    default:
        // Allow other WordPress 'ordery' values as defined in http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters
        $query_vars["orderby"] = $orderby;
        break;
}
return $query_vars;
}

Had a go at trying to create a filter (still new to php, but had a go with the following).
If anyone has any suggestions on how the above code could be changed to move the out of stock products to the end of the pages, or how the below filter could be changed to achieve that, it would be really appreciated:
add_filter('posts_clauses', 'order_by_stock_status');
function order_by_stock_status($posts_clauses) {
global $wpdb;
// only change query on wp-e-commerce loops
if (!is_admin() && (is_productQuery() || is_wpsc_product_category() || is_product_tag() ||          is_wpsc_cat.taxonomy_id())) {
$posts_clauses['join'] .= " INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta istockstatus ON ($wpdb->posts.ID =    istockstatus.post_id) ";
$posts_clauses['orderby'] = " istockstatus.meta_value ASC, " . $posts_clauses['orderby'];
$posts_clauses['where'] = " AND istockstatus.meta_key = '_stock_status' AND istockstatus.meta_value <>  '' " . $posts_clauses['where'];
}
return $posts_clauses;
}

